# How can I improve this Reinforced Learning scenario in Stable Baselines3?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

In this scenario, I present a box observation with numbers 0, 1 or 2 and shape (1, 10).
The odds for 0 and 2 are 2% each, and 96% for 1.
I want the model to learn to pick the index of any 2 that comes. If it doesn't have a 2, just choose 0.

Bellow is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import gym
from gym import spaces
from stable_baselines3 import PPO, DQN, A2C
from stable_baselines3.common.env_util import make_vec_env
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import VecFrameStack


action_length = 10

class TestBot(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestBot, self).__init__()
        self.total_rewards = 0
        self.time = 0

        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(action_length)
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=2, shape=(1, action_length), dtype=np.float32)
    
    def generate_next_obs(self):
        p = [0.02, 0.02, 0.96]
        a = [0, 2, 1]
        self.observation = np.random.choice(a, size=(1, action_length), p=p)
        if 2 in self.observation[0][1:]:
            self.best_reward += 1

    def reset(self):
        if self.time != 0:
            print('Total rewards: ', self.total_rewards, 'Best possible rewards: ', self.best_reward)

        self.best_reward = 0
        self.time = 0
        self.generate_next_obs()
        self.total_rewards = 0
        self.last_observation = self.observation
        return self.observation

    def step(self, action):
        reward = 0
        if action != 0:
            last_value = self.last_observation[0][action]
            if last_value == 2:
                reward = 1
            else:
                reward = -1
        self.time += 1
        self.generate_next_obs()
        done = self.time == 4096
        info = {}
        self.last_observation = self.observation
        self.total_rewards += reward
        return self.observation, reward, done, info
```

For training, I used the following:

```
env = TestBot()
env = make_vec_env(lambda: env, n_envs=1)
model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=0)

iters = 0
while True:
    iters += 1
    model.learn(total_timesteps=4096, reset_num_timesteps=True)
```

PPO gave the best result, which wasn't so great. It learned to have positive rewards, but took a long time and got stuck in a point far from optimal.

How can I improve the learning of this scenario?

Comment: You next state is totally independent of your action and of your previous state, so you're violating Markov assumption, therefore it is very hard for your model to learn

Comment: Hey, thank you for the comment. I might be wrong, but doesn't Markov assumption only state that the next state should not be dependent of previous states? Meaning that, if the next state is not dependent of anything, the assumption is not broken.

Comment: For example, the problem I'm trying to solve could represent a randomly generated space where you want to pick only good fruits that come to your way and not the bad fruits. Does it violate Markov's assumption?

Comment: you have a conditional probability in your RL state transitions chain and Markov assumption or property assumes that this transition solely depends on the current state, while yours relies on the random sampling from some distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by tunning the PPO parameters.

I had to change the following parameters:

- gamma: from 0.99 to 0. It determines the importance of future rewards in the decision-making process. A value of 0 means that only imediate rewards should be considered.
- gae_lambda: from 0.95 to 0.65. The gae_lambda parameter in Reinforcement Learning is used in the calculation of the Generalized Advantage Estimation (GAE). GAE is a method for estimating the advantage function in reinforcement learning, which is a measure of how much better a certain action is compared to the average action. A lower value means that PPO doesn't need to use the GAE too much.
- clip_range: from 0.2 to function based. It determines the percentage of the decisions that will be done for exploration. At the end, exploration starts to be irrelevant. So, I made a function that uses a high exploration in the first few iteractions and goes to 0 at the end.

I also made a small modification in the environment in order to penalize more the loss of oportunity of picking a number 2 index, but that is done just to accelerate the training.

The following is my final code:

```
env = TestBot()
env = make_vec_env(lambda: env, n_envs=1)

iters = 0

def clip_range_schedule():
    def real_clip_range(progress):
        global iters
        cr = 0.2
        if iters > 20:
            cr = 0.0
        elif iters > 12:
            cr = 0.05
        elif iters > 6:
            cr = 0.1
        return cr
    return real_clip_range

model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose=0, gamma=0.0, gae_lambda=0.65, clip_range=clip_range_schedule())

while True:
    iters += 1
    model.learn(total_timesteps=4096, reset_num_timesteps=True)
```